# SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint 2010 Foundation which I am trying to upgrade to 2013 Foundation. Here is how I want to do it:

I have two different facilities each with a Functional Web Server and SQL server. If the user is in facility A, then he needs to be directed to Server A in facility A and if the sser is in facility B, he needs to be directed to the Server in facility B.

This way the user does not have to reach the SharePoint Server in Facility B since he is in facility B and no traffic will be going through MPLS. Both servers will be containing same exact data and content (So, I am thinking 2 tire sharepoint!) How can I accomplish this?

Will the two tire farm work with two individual SharePoint and database servers at each site and sharing the same content? I can have GPO direct users to different websites depending on their Domain Controller which is not a problem.

My question is, How can I have two sites  servers sharing the same exact content. Lets say one server is in Europe and one is in US and both need to host Exact same content. Isn't that what 2 tire topology is used for?

Comment: Two tier topology would be having a set of sharepoint server and sql servers. What you are referring to is content replication which is tricky in real time. Is there any specific reason why you want to have 2 separate farms and redirect users locally? Is there limitations on network or bandwidth?

Comment: Thank you Manu, yes here is. The servers are on two different facilities and the traffic will be going through MPLS which slows down the process. Is there any other alternative you can think of or any other method to speed up this process while checking in and out documents on the website?

Comment: If your traffic is over a slow network (high latency) then most of the replication solutions will struggle to work and you may not get the result you hope to see. All the documents and data (most of it) in SharePoint stays in SQL Server by default and hence if you want local server farms to have same data then ideally we should sync your SQL Servers in both DCs which is a pain with high latency network. Have you considered a cloud option, I mean something like Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

What you might try to build is a so called "stretched farm" across two datacenters. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748824%28v=office.15%29.aspx#CfgStretchedFarm

From your description, non of the requirements on bandwidth and latency are fullfilled.

There are 3rd party products on the market that address your issue. You need to set up two separate SharePoint-Farms in your two locations and synchronize the content live or scheduled (depending on your changes and bandwidth). Look for vendors like AvePoint or Metalogix.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/christwe/archive/2013/10/24/stretched-farm-and-database-replication-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Stretched farms are best suited if the datacenters are in close proximity to each other with <1ms latency between them.